# Как добавить элемент из списка 1 в словарь в списке 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dict

Есть список словарей:

```
[{'car': 'bentley', 'model': 'continental'}, {'car': 'maserati', 'model': 'levante'}]
```

Есть список элементов
`['0', '1']`
Как объединить их, чтобы получилось:

```
[{'car': 'bentley', 'model': 'continental', 'available' : '0' }, {'car': 'maserati', 'model': 'levante', 'available' : '1'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = [{'car': 'bentley', 'model': 'continental'}, {'car': 'maserati', 'model': 'levante'}]
bar = [0, 1]

result = [dict(item, available=bar[index]) for index, item in enumerate(foo)]
print(result)

#[{'car': 'bentley', 'model': 'continental', 'available': 0}, {'car': 'maserati', 'model': 'levante', 'available': 1}]
```

Comment: можно ещё использовать `zip`